# Can a function have a turning point (maxima) and yet its derivative not equal zero?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, mathematical-physics

[the graph of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nonB.jpg)[The graph of the function[the graph of the first derivative of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8GT.jpg)The attached graph shows the existence of turning point but the first derivative of the graphed function is never zero anywhere within the domain of the function. What does this mean?
[image: graph of the function]

Comment: What has this to do with mathematical physics ? And what with graph theory ?

Comment: Also , which graph do you mean ? The orange graph has a place where the first derivate is $0$. The blue graph does not represent a function

Comment: What's supposed to be the function? The orange graph or the blue dots?

Comment: For future reference, "graph theory" is not about x-y graphs (which is an unfortunate confusion), but instead about networks with vertices/nodes and edges. Like how "linear programming" is not about coding or programming languages, but optimization models with only linear constraints.

Comment: @Peter Both graphs seem to be dots clouds, so they may well define functions – but those would be functions on a discrete set of arguments, hence nod differentiable. One may infer  some continuous approximations and then we can talk about derivatives, but not with dot-cloud graphs alone.

Comment: please add a plot of the first derivitive as well.

Comment: The graph of the derivative is obviously incorrect. How did you compute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the derivative exists, then it must equal zero. However, a function may have a turning point at which its derivative does not exist: for example, $y = |x|$ has a local minimum at $x = 0$, but its derivative does not exist at that point.

Comment: Could the OP please explain how this answer solves their problem?